# Galaxy Nexus-adbd cannot run as root in production builds

Tags: ubuntu-touch

When pushing quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip, I get an error message "adbd cannot run as root in production builds" and the ubuntu flash fails.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow carefully the installation instructions for unlocking the device

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_2_-_Device_unlock
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_3_-_Initial_Device_Setup

if this has been proceeded sucessfully you should be able to flash the device.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the link. In general I feel this is 100% right and I normally do not tend to just giving links. But in this case we have a list of steps which have to be followed carefully and I think it's better not to copy with the risk of missing some important details. Even more important if the ubuntu wiki is updated we will have only one **right** source instead of two different versions.